# Prevent custom cursor to expand page

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a custom cursor but when it goes at the bottom of the page, it is expanding the height of the page. Is there a way to prevent that?

I've tried to get the initial height of the page using Javascript and then set a `max-height` to the body but it doesn't work.

To test this issue, you can check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kjbrum/pen/qooQJJ) and take the cursor to the bottom of the window, you will see the scrollbar expand.

**Edit:** I am using the custom cursor on a complete page and it must keep the ability to scroll the page but once at the bottom of the page, the cursor should not expand it.

**Edit 2 :** Here is my layout :

```
<body>
    <div class="cursor-fix"> <!-- the wrapper to fix the problem -->
        <header></header>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `position:`<del>`absolute`</del>`fixed`
2. `self.endY =`<del>`e.pageY`</del>`e.pageY - window.scrollY`

[Demo](https://codepen.io/devanshj/pen/ZZqgbq?editors=0010). Does this work for you?

Comment: Indeed, it does the trick. Thank you very much for your help! (I have to wait 23 hours to award you the bounty, be sure I won't forget)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want people to be able to use that cursor normally but, at the moment, when it gets to the bottom of the page the bottom half of the circle causes the size of the page to be greater.

In that case, wrap your page in a container that has `overflow: hidden` but make that container use the full height of the page (depends on the layout of the page, if you give your full page layout I can be more specific on how to do it). That way they can scroll through the page using the overflow of the body element but can't change the size of the "cursor" container because it's overflow is set to hidden.

If you are ok with having fixed sizes then also giving a `height` value to the `<html>` and `overflow:hidden` will do the trick.

**EDIT**: I edited your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RdJObW) to show what I mean, note that I edited your script to use CSS transforms instead of absolute positioning, I couldn't get it to work otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to wrap all the page in a container but it didn't work. It still expand the page and the expanded part is not part of the container and not even part of the html tag. It's just "there".

Comment: I forgot to mention the container has to have a fixed height. Actually, either the container or the body element have to have a fixed height.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've tried but it still doesn't work. I've edited my question with my layout.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've just figured out that I didn't put the right codepen on the original post. Maybe this is why your solution still doesn't work on my site. Could you please have a look on the new codepen?